# Jupyter Notebook cannot access Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I've created my first Jupyter Notebook in Google cloud. I've followed the instructions here
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/use-r-bigquery

to use R with BQ. However, when I try to run the code I keep getting
*"Error: Access Denied: Project ABC: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project ABC. [accessDenied] "* where ABC is my project ID.

I've added BigQuery User & Admin permissions, logout, and logged back in, but keep getting the same message.

Comment: "BigQuery Data Editor" + "BigQuery Job User" roles in IAM. You can also use BigQuery with Google Colab which might be easier for the setup. https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/bigquery.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to verify the [Manage access using IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/manage-access) documentation where is mentioned  how to add the required permissions to access to the dataset in BigQuery.

Due to the error message:
*Error: Access Denied: Project ABC: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project ABC. [accessDenied] "* you need to add the [permission](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions) **bigquery.jobs.create** to the user or service account used.

In the Compute Engine menu you can check the service account used in the Notebook, confirm that that service account has all the permissions mentioned above or the BigQuery Admin role mentioned in your question.